# Choosing pairs of numbers with distinct bounded sum

Tags: problem-solving

Stumbled across this problem in the list of examples for high school math exam, paraphrasing a little:

```
What is the maximum number of pairs with integers from 1 to 22 you can choose,
with each pair having a distinct sum that would not exceed 27?
```

After playing with numbers for a bit, my intuition tells me that it's definitely not 11, but what is the correct answer (seems like 9, because I can't make 10), and more importantly, how to prove it, I have no idea. 
Does anyone have some idea of the approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10 pairs: (17,10),(14,12),(21,4),(13,11),(20,3),(16,6),(19,2),(18,1),(9,8),(7,5) are disjoint and have distinct sums in the range 12-22.

If 11 pairs were possible, then their total sum would be 1+2+...+22=253. But the greatest possible sum for 11 pairs with distinct sums is 17+18+...+27=242. So 11 pairs are not possible.

Comment: op said pairs have distinct sums, he didnt say numbers are distinct .

Comment: Guess I didn't try hard enough to make 10 pairs, is it just from trial and error?

Comment: @Agawa001 The question would be trivial if you took that interpretation. It also does not square well with his comments in the last paragraph.

Comment: @swish Yes, more or less.